# Get the org.gradle.api.DefaultProject object of an existing Gradle Project?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-tooling-api

**Question**

How do I interact with `Gradle Projects` programmatically?

**Context**

I need to retrieve the Build Information provided in:

```
org.gradle.api.DefaultProject.
```

But I see no way of getting the Project/SourceSets/Configuration container objects through `java`.

All the documentation I see describes how to achieve this using `groovy DSL`.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by 'programmatically'? do you write a custom plugin?

Comment: Not exactly a custom plugin. If I were to use a plugin. I'd need to add apply plugin in the build.gradle to use them. I am writing a Java application that probes other Gradle Projects and uses their Build and Gradle Info. I don't want my application to be intrusive and make changes to the build scripts of the gradle projects.

Comment: I didn't get the idea: gradle objects (like DefaultProject object) exist in the jvm running gradle, how are you expecting to access them from your application?

Comment: @AdamSkywalker Thanks for responding :). I see what you mean, So is there no means to collect project Information like SourceSet and ConfigurationContainer of a gradle project through an external application?

Comment: yes, it is impossible :)